# Differential drive node?

Tags: ros, differential-drive

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a two-wheeled platform controlled by an Arduino that reports motor encoder counts. So I don't reinvent the wheel, I'm looking for a pre-existing ROS node that can convert those counts into standard odometry and tf messages. Is there a standard ROS package that implements this?

I found [this differential_drive project](http://wiki.ros.org/differential_drive), but it appears to be dead and doesn't have a Kinetic package available.

I also found [this differential_drive_controller project](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller), but it appears to be more high-level and doesn't support listening to motor encoders directly. I'd still need to implement a custom node to convert my motor encoder messages to joint messages, so if I need to overcome that overhead, it would make more sense to just implement the odometry reporting myself instead of running two separate nodes in memory.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258854/differential-drive-node?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2017-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've used `differential_drive` in Indigo and Jade. You cannot install via rpm but can get the source from GitHub and add to your catkin_src. The original code was for Groovy, but the author has incorporated some changes I supplied to make the package more ROS-up-to-date and remove compile warnings for Hydro and above. (https://github.com/jfstepha/differential-drive)

That said, I no longer use `differential_drive` for these reasons:

- I intended to use `differential_drive` together with `rosserial_python` to talk to an Arduino-based robot controller. However, `rosserial` proved unreliable on Arduino-class devices with only 2kb RAM, so I had to abandon that approach.
- I shifted to using `ros_arduino_bridge`, which incorporates the functionality that `differential_drive` supplies, so I no longer needed it.

If you decide to use `differential_drive`, a few observations:

- `differential_drive` incorporates a PID controller in Python to send motor controls via ROS messages. However, the author of `differential_drive` doesn't recommend that method any more. (From email communication.) He recommends instead putting the PID controller closer to the motor control hardware.
- `differential_drive` mixes units at times. For example, motor commands sent by the node are in m/s, while odometry returned from the motor control system is in encoder ticks per second.

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2017-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1